# Bedrock WordPress

Tags: redirect

Bedrock google analytics problem.

- I have used **Bedrock** in one of my wordpress project.
- But google webmaster search console display that the page is automatically redirects to the /web.

Please suggest for the same to ignore redirect for the google analytic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your .env file. It should be sth like this:

```
WP_ENV=production
WP_HOME=http://yourdomain.com
WP_SITEURL=${WP_HOME}/wp
```

Also check that your DocumentRoot in Apache config points to /path/to/your/website/**web**

https://roots.io/bedrock/docs/installing-bedrock/

You could also check in discourse from Roots for a problem like that: https://discourse.roots.io/